# YouTube Push Notifications via Webhooks & PubSubHubbub (Python3) returning 200 on subscription, but nothing on video upload

Tags: python-3.x, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, webhooks

I've added a Webhooks listener to a Discord bot, and I'm trying to use that to post notifications to a text channel when a new video is uploaded (trying to eliminate my reliance on MEE6). When I subscribe to notifications at https://pubsubhubbub.appspot.com/subscribe, I get a `200` response, and my server's console prints

> 66.249.84.174 - - [27/Apr/2021 05:23:51] "GET /webhooks?hub.topic=https://www.youtube.com/xml/feeds/videos.xml%3Fchannel_id%<THE_CHANNEL_ID_I_WANT_NOTIFICATIONS_FOR>&hub.challenge=<A_BUNCH_OF_NUMBERS>&hub.mode=subscribe&hub.lease_seconds=432000 HTTP/1.1" 200 -

However, when a video gets uploaded nothing happens.

I've tried manually triggering a POST request from PostMan to the same endpoint (with the XML body found here https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/push_notifications as the raw->xml body text), and that seems to hit my console and return a `200`, but I'm at a loss as to why I'm not getting any indication when an upload goes up. Code below:

```
from flask import Flask, Response, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/webhooks', methods=['POST'])
def respond():
    print(request.json);
    return Response(status=200)

@app.route('/webhooks')
def index():
    print(('request', request))
    print('args:', request.args)  # display text in console
    print('form:', request.form)
    print('data:', request.data)
    print('json:', request.json)
    print('files:', request.files)
    
    return request.args.get('data', 'none')  # send text to web browser

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=<MY_PORT>)
```

I'm hosting on PebbleHost, which is why the host is set to 0.0.0.0; there's a separate IP I'm connecting to for the subscriptions, mapped to a dedicated port. I'm quite new to Webhooks, and this is my first time interacting with the YouTube API, so I'm certain there's something really obvious I'm overlooking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to return `hub.challenge` for confirmation on subscription.

A Working Example that I made earlier.

```
from flask import Flask, request
import xmltodict

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/callback", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def callback():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = xmltodict.parse(request.data)
        print(data)
        return request.data
    else:
        return request.args.get('hub.challenge')



app.run('0.0.0.0')
```

Comment: That's the first little quote, 
> > 66.249.84.174 - - [27/Apr/2021 05:23:51] "GET /webhooks?hub.topic=https://www.youtube.com/xml/feeds/videos.xml%3Fchannel_id%<THE_CHANNEL_ID_I_WANT_NOTIFICATIONS_FOR>&hub.challenge=<A_BUNCH_OF_NUMBERS>&hub.mode=subscribe&hub.lease_seconds=432000 HTTP/1.1" 200 -

Comment: Did you tried that by returning hub.challenge?

Comment: It do take 20-30 seconds just after uploading.... and also I tried running above snippet, it just works for me :)